# draggable and droppable not giving latest position?

Tags: php, jquery

Please have a look in to my code below

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'fit',
    revert: true,
});

$("#droppable").droppable({
    accept: '.drag',
    activeClass: "drop-area",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
            $("#placeholderimg").css("visibility", "show");
            x = ui.helper.clone();
            ui.helper.remove();
            x.draggable({
                helper: 'original',
                cursor: 'move',
                containment: '#droppable',
                tolerance: 'fit',
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    $(ui.draggable).remove();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The Process :-
User will have some images on LHS and they will grag those into rightside panel 
But the problem is when I move that dragged image new position is not getting .Actually I am hoping to get new position after image is  moved to some position and leave .

Please help

Comment: Can you please provide your html also. It would be easy to understand

Comment: @yeshansachithak sorry bit that is too big this is similar example but just need final x-y position as per container instead of body http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DGbT3/3/